# How to UNHIDE caller ID for contacts on dual sim phone

Tags: applications

My phone is Alcatel POP3 (5054D) dual sim with android 5.1.1
I would realy like to call 'anonymous' if the person I call is not in my contact list (e.g. a customer).
I tried secretsheep-like apps, but none worked correctly (my number showed for non-contacts). So actualy I call always with hidden ID but I wish to change that.

When I manualy add the 'show ID' code prefix then my number shows-up. UNFortunaltely when I reprogram my contacts with the prefix, I can't send SMS to my contacts because of wrong number...

Can anybody help?

Comment: Similar category, but have you tried a call prefixer? The app [Prefixer](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.tftbelow.prefixer) e.g. claims even dual-SIM support. As that doesn't manipulate your contact list, it shouldn't have effect on your SMS. [Telefonate prefix](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=marco.android.telefono) is a similar app. Hoewever, permissions look a bit strange, so make sure to check that before installing. Check [here](https://android.izzysoft.de/applists/category/named/office_contacts_various) for alternatives (Ctrl-F "prefix").